# I am trying to install Go lang packages but it gives error like this ::error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, go

My Go intellisense autocompletion is not working, I am trying to install gocode and gopkg but it is failed and gives git error like:::

```
cd /home/poojat/go/src/golang.org/x/tools; git pull --ff-only
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    CONTRIBUTING.md
    README
    blog/blog.go
    cmd/bundle/main.go
    cmd/callgraph/main.go
    cmd/callgraph/main_test.go
    cmd/callgraph/testdata/src/pkg/pkg_test.go
    cmd/compilebench/main.go
    cmd/digraph/digraph.go
    cmd/fiximports/main.go
    cmd/fiximports/main_test.go
    cmd/getgo/download.go
    cmd/getgo/download_test.go
    cmd/getgo/main.go
    cmd/getgo/main_test.go
    cmd/getgo/path.go
    cmd/getgo/path_test.go
    cmd/getgo/server/main.go
    cmd/getgo/steps.go
    cmd/getgo/system.go
    cmd/godex/print.go
    cmd/godoc/README.godoc-app
    cmd/godoc/appinit.go
    cmd/godoc/autocert.go
    cmd/godoc/blog.go
    cmd/godoc/dl.go
    cmd/godoc/doc.go
    cmd/godoc/godoc19_test.go
    cmd/godoc/godoc_test.go
    cmd/godoc/handlers.go
    cmd/godoc/main.go
    cmd/godoc/play.go
    cmd/godoc/remotesearch.go
    cmd/godoc/x.go
    cmd/goimports/doc.go
    cmd/goimports/goimports.go
    cmd/gomvpkg/main.go
    cmd/gorename/gorename_test.go
    cmd/goyacc/yacc.go
    cmd/guru/callees.go
    cmd/guru/callers.go
    cmd/guru/callstack.go
    cmd/guru/describe.go
    cmd/guru/guru.go
    cmd/guru/guru_test.go
    cmd/guru/implements.go
    cmd/guru/main.go
    cmd/guru/referrers.go
    cmd/guru/serial/serial.go
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/describe-json/main.go
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/describe-json/main.golden
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/describe/main.go
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/describe/main.golden
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/referrers-json/main.golden
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/referrers/int_test.go
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/referrers/main.go
    cmd/guru/testdata/src/referrers/main.golden
    cmd/present/appengine.go
    cmd/present/dir.go
    cmd/present/doc.go
    cmd/present/local.go
    cmd/present/play.go
    cmd/present/play_http.go
    cmd/present/play_socket.go
    cmd/present/static/slides.js
    cmd/present/static/styles.css
    cmd/present/templates/slides.tmpl
    cmd/ssadump/main.go
    cmd/stress/stress.go
    cmd/stringer/endtoend_test.go
    cmd/stringer/golden_test.go
    cmd/stringer/stringer.go
    cmd/tip/Dockerfile
    cmd/tip/Makefile
    cmd/tip/README
    cmd/tip/cert.go
    cmd/tip/godoc.go
    cmd/tip/godoc.yaml
    cmd/tip/talks.go
    cmd/tip/tip-rc.yaml
    cmd/tip/tip.go
    cmd/toolstash/main.go
    container/intsets/sparse.go
    container/intsets/sparse_test.go
    cover/profile.go
    go/ast/astutil/imports.go
    go/ast/astutil/imports_test.go
    go/buildutil/allpackages_test.go
    go/buildutil/fakecontext.go
    go/buildutil/util_test.go
    go/callgraph/cha/cha.go
    go/callgraph/cha/cha_test.go
    go/callgraph/rta/rta.go
    go/gcexportdata/example_test.go
    go/gcexportdata/gcexportdata.go
    go/gcexportdata/main.go
    go/gcimporter15/bexport.go
    go/gcimporter15/bexport19_test.go
    go/gcimporter15/bexport_test.go
    go/gcimporter15/bimport.go
    go/gcimporter15/exportdata.go
    go/gcimporter15/gcimporter.go
    go/gcimporter15/gcimporter_test.go
    go/gcimporter15/isAlias18.go
    go/gcimporter15/isAlias19.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/a.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/b.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/exports.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/issue15920.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/issue20046.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/p.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/versions/test.go
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/versions/test_go1.7_0.a
    go/gcimporter15/testdata/versions/test_go1.7_1.a
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/backdoor.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/gccgoinstallation.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/gccgoinstallation_test.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/importer.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/importer19_test.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/importer_test.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/parser.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/parser_test.go
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/testdata/alias.gox
    go/internal/gccgoimporter/testenv_test.go
    go/loader/cgo.go
    go/loader/cgo_pkgconfig.go
    go/loader/loader.go
    go/loader/loader_test.go
    go/loader/stdlib_test.go
    go/pointer/api.go
    go/pointer/doc.go
    go/pointer/pointer_test.go
    go/pointer/query.go
    go/pointer/query_test.go
    go/pointer/reflect.go
    go/ssa/builder.go
    go/ssa/const.go
    go/ssa/create.go
    go/ssa/doc.go
    go/ssa/example_test.go
    go/ssa/interp/external.go
    go/ssa/interp/interp.go
    go/ssa/interp/interp_test.go
    go/ssa/interp/ops.go
    go/ssa/interp/testdata/complit.go
    go/ssa/methods.go
    go
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    README.md
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: Did you change those files? If so, you will want to commit them.

Answer (score 2):

That may be because you have changes in those files that are not commited.

Try:

```
cd /home/poojat/go/src/golang.org/x/tools
git checkout . 
git clean -fd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I get this error now: ```error: unable to unlink old 'internal/lsp/analysis/fillreturns/fillreturns.go': Permission denied```